# justify text in HtmlTextBox of telerik reporting

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-reporting

I use telerik report Q1 2013 for reporting. I have a HtmlTextBox in my form with following value:
`<p style="text-align:justify">{Parameters.matn.Value}</p>`

but after rendering report my css code disapear and a new `<p>` with s0 class is generated automatically! how can I justify my text in htmlTextBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can able to justify TextBox from Properties pane, but we cant justify HtmlTextBox because of limitation said by Telerik Team.

[please go to this link for more clarification](http://www.telerik.com/forums/justify-text-align#yUGKyrW2eECLrmnnpNAFVg)

Comment: I knew that... I have problem with HtmltextBox, not Textbox... thanks for your answer.